# Raspberrypi Python code not working proprely

Tags: shell, command-line, python, raspberry-pi, email

I want use this code to get cpu temperature from my raspberry_pi and  if the temperature is too high sending an warn email , the code show below:

```
# coding=utf-8
import os
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


# At First we have to get the current CPU-Temperature with this defined function
def getCPUtemperature():
    res = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').readline()
    return (res.replace("temp=", "").replace("'C\n", ""))


# Now we convert our value into a float number
temp = float(getCPUtemperature())

# Check if the temperature is abouve 30°C (test with 30)

if (temp > 30):
    # Enter your smtp Server-Connection
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtpmail.provider.com', 587)
    # if your using gmail: smtp.gmail.com
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo
    # Login
    server.login("your email or username", "your Password")
    
    # Now comes the Text we want to send:
    value = "Critical warning! The actual temperature is: " + getCPUtemperature()
    msg = MIMEText(value)
    # The Subject of your E-Mail
    msg['Subject'] = "Critical warning! Temperature:" + getCPUtemperature()
    # Consigner of your E-Mail
    msg['From'] = "Raspberry Pi"
    # recipient of your E-Mail
    msg['To'] = "recipient@gmail.com"
    # Finally send the mail
    server.sendmail("consigner@gmail.com", "recipient@gmail.com", msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
    print "Everything was working fine! Best regards www.quaintproject.wordpress.com"
```

this code should working and had previous successful examples  , but when I run it the output like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo nano tempwarn.py
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python tempwarn.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tempwarn.py", line 20, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtpmail.provider.com', 587)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 317, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

why it has this kind of error? and im pretty sure the 587 is correct setting for gmail.

Comment: You should read the code. It tells you to swap `smtpmail.provider.com` to `smtp.gmail.com`.

Comment: thanks very much , sorry I just miss that .

Comment: @Norman If you have a solution to your issue, then please post it as a proper answer. I have removed your "(Solved)" in the question's title. A question is resolved by [accepting a submitted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Could I just delete this post? becasue it seems not helping other and its my mistke.@Kusalananda

Comment: No, no more deleting questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

swap smtpmail.provider.com to smtp.gmail.com